# Is there a way to redo a merge in git?

Tags: git

So I made a pretty big mistake. I made a commit, pulled, merged (but messed up the code while doing so) and then pushed. I'd like to redo that merge and get the code right. Is there any way to do this?

I use bitbucket.

Comment: Just a note - this is actually **on-topic** on SO, and should *not* have been migrated. Try reading your own help pages sometime and note the *software tools commonly used by programmers* line. That said, it is also on-topic here - SwiftCore, don't feel bad that it was migrated, that was not your fault.

Answer (score 21):

Not sure if this is the "blessed" way to do it, but here's what I did to resolve the same problem without having to "force push" or anything gross like that.

Let's assume your history looks something like this (and M is the flubbed merge):

```
-A--B--C--M (master points here)
  \      /
   D----E
```

Running `git checkout -b merge_fix <commit ID E>` creates a branch before we made any mistakes:

```
-A--B--C--M (master points here)
  \      /
   D----E (HEAD and merge_fix point here)
```

Now, let's re-do the merge on our new branch.  We can't just merge in `master`, so we need to manually pick the commit before our bad merge: `git merge <commit ID C>` Don't make the same mistakes you did last time!

```
-A--B--C--M (master points here)
  \      X
   D----E-G (HEAD and merge_fix point here)
```

Assuming that commit `G` looks good, now we want to sync up with the top of the `master` branch.  This command tells git to ignore the changes that were made to master, and force our changes to become the merge result: `git merge -s ours master`

```
-A--B--C--M (master points here)
  \      X  \
   D----E-G--H (HEAD and merge_fix point here)
```

Finally, (again assuming that commit `H` looks good, we want to fast-forward `master` to include our fixed merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge merge_fix
```

This really just moves the `master` branch pointer to `H`, but I'll take the opportunity to clean up my ASCII art a bit:

```
-A--B--C--M--H (HEAD, master, and merge_fix all point here)
  \      X  /
   D----E--G
```

And there you have it! you've successfully re-done the merge without invalidating any history!

Comment: It should be noted that if any further commits were made beyond `M` before beginning to fix, their changes might be overwritten by this method. I've had success in preserving these changes by **skipping** `git merge -s ours master`, instead immediately doing `git checkout master`, then finally `git merge -s resolve merge_fix`. This alternate method works best if those further commits are not in conflict with `merge_fix`.

Comment: @AgentRev the changes are not overwritten if the steps are followed like there are no additional commits beyond `M`, and `git merge -s ours M` is done with the "fubbed" commit `M` first. This step is basically just discarding `M` changes. And then it can be merged with master's HEAD.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it, like this:

1. Reset to the commit before your merge.
2. Perform the merge again
3. Force push

That is:

```
git reset --hard SHA1
git merge branchname
git commit
git push --force remotename branchname
```

Just keep in mind that `git push --force` will rewrite whatever you had at the remote branch, and other people using that branch may be affected by this too. (Normally you should not do this.)

Comment: Just remember doing ```git push --force``` is not safe

Comment: save alternative to `git push --force` is `git push --force-with-lease`; e.g. in the last step use `git push --force-with-lease remotename branchname`

Answer (score 3):

`git merge --abort`
and then you can merge again

Comment: I just get a "there is no merge to abort" message

Comment: This can only be done when there are merge conflicts.

Comment: why the minus one? this helped me.

Comment: Because the question is about when you have already finished the merge (incorrectly) and pushed.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
git checkout . 
git merge --abort
```

this will undo any local changes during merge, and then revert back to pre-merge state. 
if you already did a commit or merge continue, you'll need to do the reset HEAD~ steps

Answer (score 0):

I had a different, somewhat more complicated setup.

there's basically three starting points:
(and the other solutions are all assuming either 1 or 2)

1. `redo-branch` should be completely merged AND 
   after the merge of `redo-branch` there have been **no other merges**
2. `redo-branch` should be completely merged AND 
   after the merge of `redo-branch` there have already been **other merges**, that should be kept
3. `redo-branch` is a **long-living branch** to be repeatedly merged AND
   **only a range of revision** was **part of the merge** AND
   there have been **other commits/merges on master** after the failed merge (**ouch**)

a setup for (3) would be

```
---A--B--C--M   (master points here)
  /        /
-X--D-----E--Y  (that's the long-living redo-branch)
```

1. you should be fine with solution https://superuser.com/a/691497/308385
2. same solution as 1 might work
3. let's get started :-)

```
# let's start on the last commit before the failed merge
git checkout redo-branch
git checkout -b D^1 new-branch-for-merge

# now let's pick all the revisions D through E
git cherry-pick D^1..E

# go to the target branch (master) and merge
git checkout master
git merge new-branch-for-merge
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this hope it's useful for you

```
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-branch-rebase.html
```

Comment: While this can answer OP question, link only answers are not well accepted on SO. You can however quote in your answer most relevant excerpts from the link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.